# Longest running sequence from all permutations of array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, data-structures, permutation

From a recent interview of Amazon, I found the following question. I could not figure out an effective way to solve it.
The problem reads as:
Given an array of strings, you need to find the longest running sequence of a character among all possible permutations of the strings in the array.
**INPUT :**
ab
ba
aac
**OUTPUT :**
a,3

Note: From the input and output set, I think the permutation of the individual strings is not to be done.
Would really appreciate if somebody can help. Thanks.

Comment: Please describe how the longest running sequence is formed. The question is not clear to me.

Comment: Title says combinations and the description says permutations.

Comment: Faruk Sahin: I have edited the title. Apologies for the mistake.

Comment: @ Petar Minchev: So in this case of you take the three strings as three alphabets (Lets say X=ab, Y=ba, Z=aac) then in the permutation XYZ (can be YZX also), the letters are as: "abbaaac". The letters comprising X or Y or Z need not to be permuted amongst themselves. So in the above sequence the consecutive sequence of the character "a" comes as three times conseutively. Hence the output.

Comment: I think, the OP means "Longest Common Subsequence"

Comment: Guys, I believe he is looking for maximal one character substring that can be achieved by concatting the different strings in any order you desire

Answer (score 2):

Lovely question. So many corner cases. I'm guessing that the whole point of this interview question is to see how many corner cases you come up.

I hope I haven't missed any.

There are essentially two ways that a character sequence could be the solution to this problem:

1) It is an interior character sequence (eg. `adddddddddddddddddb`)

2) It is the concatentation of a suffix, the entire collection of strings consisting only of that character, and a prefix. In this case, no string may be used more than once, including the case where a character is the suffix *and* the prefix of the same string. (To avoid resuing the homogenous strings, the suffixes and prefixes must be strict; i.e. not the entire string).

Case 1 is easy. We simply remember a single character and sequence length, and the current character and sequence length. As we read in the strings, if the current character/sequence length is longer than the maximum, we replace the maximum. We don't need to worry about it conflicting with the computations done for Case 2, because it won't affect the result.

Case 2 is a lot more work. For each character, we need to keep some data. We can either use a fixed-size array, one entry per character in the alphabet, if the alphabet is small, or we can use a hash-table of characters. Both are `O(1)` on average; since the number of characters we'll deal with cannot be larger than the total number of characters in all the strings, the size requirement of the hash-table can be thought of as `O(N)`. (In fact, it is limited by the size of the alphabet, so just as with the fixed-size array, the storage requirement is technically `O(1)` but in the case of Unicode, for example, the constant is rather large.)

Now, what data do we need? Strings which are just a repetition of a single character are easy; we need the total length of those strings. So every time we find such a string, we can add its length to the total length member of the entry in our per-character data.

For (strict) suffixes and prefixes, it seems like we only need to maintain a maximum length for each. But what if we encounter a string whose prefix and suffix sequences are the same character, and both of the sequences are longer than any that we've handled previously? We can't use the string as both suffix and prefix. Fortunately, there is a simple answer: we keep three values: maximum_prefix, maximum_suffix, maximum_sum. If we're updating the table after reading a word, and it turns out that the same character is both prefix and suffix, we update the three values as follows:

```
maximum_sum = max(maximum_sum, 
                  prefix_length + maximum_suffix,
                  suffix_length + maximum_prefix)
maximum_prefix = max(maximum_prefix, prefix_length)
maximum_suffix = max(maximum_suffix, suffix_length)
```

Note that the above pseudo-code works just fine (if a bit wastefully) if either prefix_length or suffix_length is 0.

So that's a total of four per-character values: `homogenous_length, maximum_sum, maximum_prefix, maximum_suffix`. At the end of the scan, we need to find the character for which `homogenous_length + maximum_sum` is the greatest; we can do that by a simple scan over the character table.

Total processing time is `O(1)` per character (for the initial scan), which is `O(N)` (where `N` is the total number of characters in the problem, plus `O(max(N, |A|))` for the final scan of the character table (`|A|` is the size of the alphabet); in other words, `O(N)`. Space requirements were described above.

Comment: does it considers the case where maximum prefix and maximum suffix are of the same word?

Comment: @user2368055: yes. maximum sum is always the best current sum of prefix and suffix of two different words.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hashmaps for that. The slowest algorithm will be to make a map of character counters for every string, and then find the maximum.

I would like to know more advanced algorithm too

Comment: This solution fails for the test case, counting characters will return a,4 - and not a,3 (Unless I misunderstood you - and then, please elaborate)

Answer (score 0):

This is my naive Ruby implementation. I will try explain how I reasoned and implemented it.

In Ruby a string isn't an enumerable so Ruby can't enumerate over it directly like Python can. That's what `str.chars.to_a` solves. It converts the string to an array of characters.

My plan was to count the number of times a character occurred in each string. `["ab", "ba", "ccc"]` would become `[{"a"=>1, "b"=>1}, {"b"=>1, "a"=>1}, {"c"=>3}]`. Then I would add the number of occurrences of each consecutive pair of hashes/dictionaries. In this example it would result in `[{"a"=>2, "b"=>2}, {"b"=>1, "a"=>1, "c"=>3}]`. The highest value in this array of hashes would then represent the longest running sequence.

The problem is that strings that contains the same character over and over again will make this algorithm break down. My solution to this is to check for these kind of strings and then concatenate these with the following string if that string contains any such character. This is implemented in the `arr_of_chararr.each` in the `max_running_sequence` method.

The pairwise addition is implemented with `Hash#merge` and a block, except for the special case when there's only one element in the array.

At last I scan the array of hashes for the max value.

```rb
class Sequence_tester
  def self.max_running_sequence(arr_of_chararr)
    reduced = []
    all_same_chars = []

    arr_of_chararr.each do |str|
      arr = str.chars.to_a
      if arr.all? {|c| c == arr.first}
        all_same_chars += arr
      else
        if !all_same_chars.empty?
          if arr.any? {|c| c == all_same_chars.first}
            arr += all_same_chars
          else
            reduced << count_char_occurrences(all_same_chars)
          end
        end
        reduced << count_char_occurrences(arr)
        all_same_chars.clear
      end
    end

    if !all_same_chars.empty?
      reduced << count_char_occurrences(all_same_chars)
    end

    max_seqs = reduced
    if reduced.length > 1
      max_seqs = reduced.each_cons(2).map do |pair|
        pair.first.merge(pair.last) {|key, oldval, newval| oldval + newval}
      end
    end

    longest_seq = max_seqs.map {|h| h.max_by {|kv| kv[1]} }.max_by {|a| a[1]}
  end

  def self.count_char_occurrences(arr)
    arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|o, h| h[o] += 1}
  end
end

input = ["a", "b", "c"]
res = Sequence_tester.max_running_sequence(input)
puts "#{res.first},#{res.last}"
input = ["abc", "abb", "abc"]
res = Sequence_tester.max_running_sequence(input)
puts "#{res.first},#{res.last}"
input = ["ab", "ba", "ccc"]
res = Sequence_tester.max_running_sequence(input)
puts "#{res.first},#{res.last}"
input = ["ada", "dd", "dd", "eedd"]
res = Sequence_tester.max_running_sequence(input)
puts "#{res.first},#{res.last}"
```

Outputs:
a,1
b,3
c,3
d,7

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class alphabet
{
      string str;
      int chars[26];

public:
       alphabet()
       {
                 for(int i=0; i < 26 ; i++)
                         chars[i] = 0;

       }

       void initialize(string s)
       {
            str = s;
            for(int pos=0 ; pos < s.length(); pos++)
                         chars[s[pos]-'a']++;
       }

       int getCount(int i)
       {
           return chars[i];
       }
};

int main()
{
    int n=3;
    alphabet *arr = new alphabet[n];
    arr[0].initialize("varun");
    arr[1].initialize("ritl");
    arr[2].initialize("hello");
    int Max =0;
    char MaxChar = ' ';
    for(int i=0; i<n-1 ; i++)
    {
            for(int j=0; j<26; j++)
            {
                    int m = arr[i].getCount(j)+ arr[i+1].getCount(j);
                    if(m > Max)
                    {
                         Max = m;
                         MaxChar = char('a' + j);
                    }
            }
    }
    cout<<"Max Char = "<<MaxChar<<" "<<Max<<" times";
    system("pause");    
}
```

Comment: I am not very clear with the question, below is my understanding :

we have to find longest occurrence of a character when individual strings can be permuted.

Answer (score 0):

In an interview, I could have come up with the basic mechanics to solve this problem, but I would have failed to write the entire, error-free solution on a whiteboard. Debugger crutch.

At any rate, here is my solution in C#.

1.) I defined the set.

```
var set = new List<string>() { "ab", "ba", "aac" };
```

2.) I assembled a generic method to assemble all permutations, recursively.

```
private static List<List<T>> GetPermutations<T>(List<T> values)
{
    if (values.Count <= 1) return new List<List<T>>() { values };

    var results = new List<List<T>>();

    var perms = GetPermutations(values.Skip(1).ToList());

    foreach (var perm in perms)
    {
        foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, perm.Count + 1))
        {
            List<T> list = new List<T>();

            list.AddRange(perm.Take(i));
            list.Add(values[0]);
            list.AddRange(perm.Skip(i));

            results.Add(list);
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

3.) I found all permutations of the set.

```
var perms = GetPermutations<string>(set);
```

4.) I defined a method to find the longest running sequence in a single string.

```
private static string LongestRunningSequence(string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return null;
    if (s.Length == 1) return s;

    var seq = new Dictionary<char, int>();

    char prev = s[0];
    int counter = 0;

    foreach (char cur in s)
    {
        if (cur == prev) // chars match
        {
            ++counter; // increment counter
        }
        else // chars don't match
        {
            prev = cur; // store new char
            counter = 1; // reset the counter
        }

        // store the higher number of characters in the sequence
        if (!seq.ContainsKey(prev)) seq.Add(prev, counter);
        else if (seq[prev] < counter) seq[cur] = counter;
    }

    char key = seq.Keys.First();
    foreach (var kvp in seq)
    {
        if (kvp.Value > seq[key]) key = kvp.Key;
    }

    return string.Join("", Enumerable.Range(0, seq[key]).Select(e => key));
}
```

5.) I defined a method that found the longest running sequence in a list of strings, taking advantage of the previous method that does so for a single string.

```
private static string LongestRunningSequence(List<string> strings)
{
    string longest = String.Empty;
    foreach (var str in strings)
    {
        var locallongest = LongestRunningSequence(str);
        if (locallongest.Length > longest.Length) longest = locallongest;
    }

    return longest;
}
```

6.) I expressed each calculated permutation as a list of single strings.

```
var strings = perms.Select(e => string.Join("", e)).ToList();
```

7.) I passed this list to the earlier method that finds the longest running sequence in a list of strings.

```
LongestRunningSequence(strings); // returns aaa
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 :4 tables needs to be maintained of length 26 
--First one keeps track of the length of the longest prefix in the string 
--Second one keeps track of the length of the longest suffix in the string 
--Third one keeps track of the TOTAL length of strings that consist entirely of a given character
--Fourth keeps track of longest character in the middle

Step 2:
--Run loop for 0 to 26 and add first[i]+second[i]+third[i] and store them in sum[i]
--find the maximum element in sum[i] and fourth table.
--index is the alphabet(0 is A) and maximum element is the length

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int pre[26],su[26],single[26],middle[26],sum[26];
int getlength(char str[][10])
{
int i,j,n=3,counter=0,max=-1,index;
char c,p;
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{
 for(i=0;i<strlen(str[j]);i++)
{
 if(i==0) 
{
  c=str[j][i];
  counter++;
  continue;
  }
    else if(i==strlen(str[j])-1&&c == str[j][i])
  {
    counter =0;
    break;
   }
  else
  {
    if(c == str[j][i])
    counter++;
    else 
     break;
   }

  }
    if(pre[toupper(c)-65]<counter)
      pre[toupper(c)-65]=counter;
      counter=0;
  }
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{
  for(i=strlen(str[j])-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
    if(i==strlen(str[j])-1)
    {
     c=str[j][i];
      counter++;
      continue;
     }
   else if(i==0&&c == str[j][i])
   {
     counter =0;
     break;
   }
   else
   {
     if(c == str[j][i])
     counter++;
   else
    break;
   }

} 
if(su[toupper(c)-65]<counter)
 su[toupper(c)-65]=counter;
 counter=0;
 }

for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{
for(i=strlen(str[j])-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
  if(i==strlen(str[j])-1)
  {
  c=str[j][i];
  counter++;
  continue;
  }
 else
{
 if(c == str[j][i])
 counter++;
 else
 {
counter=0;   
 break;
 }
}

 }
    if(single[toupper(c)-65]<counter)
      single[toupper(c)-65]=counter;
      counter=0;
}
counter=0;
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{
  for(i=1;i<strlen(str[j])-1;i++)
{
if(i==1)
 {
   c=str[j][i];

   counter++;
 }
  else
 {
   if(c == str[j][i])
 {

   counter++;
  }
 else
 {
 if(middle[toupper(c)-65]<counter)
   middle[toupper(c)-65]=counter;
   counter=1;
   c=str[j][i];
  }

} 
}
 counter=0;
}

 for(i=0;i<26;i++)
{
  sum[i]=pre[i]+su[i]+single[i];
   if(sum[i]>max)
 {
   max=sum[i];
   index=i;
  }
}

for(i=0;i<26;i++)
{

if(middle[i]>max)
{
max=middle[i];
index=i;
}
  }
   printf("\n length %d index %d",max,index);


  }
void main()
{
char arr[3][10]={"bbbb","dccccccar","vaa"};
getlength(arr);
}
```